# git: making me manually merge files I didn't touch

Tags: git

Say I create a branch based on main; for our simplified example, main has a single folder:

- alpha

This specific folder contains API HTML docs which is regularly copied into that folder.

In my new branch, I add a new folder, beta, and *solely* work inside that:

- alpha
- beta

At some point down the line I wanted to merge the changes from main into my branch.

I would expect no having any merge issues.

Instead I'm getting conflicts in files in alpha, between the latest changes in main (HEAD) and the same lines as they were when I created the branch.

Surely the changes from HEAD should be ones used, without a need for a merge?

Is there any way from the command line, when performing such a merge, to specify that the changes for HEAD for all files in a particularly folder should be accepted?

P.

Comment: If you're getting merge conflicts with files inside alpha then your branch must have changed files inside alpha

Comment: Makes no sense: if you are merging main into the branch, main is not HEAD. You sound very confused about what you are doing and what a merge is. Please show the _actual commands_ you are giving to git and explain what happens as a result.

Comment: I would check my assumptions first. Find the merge-base of the two branches (`git merge-base <branch1> <branch2>`). Once you have that, check with `git diff` how each branch differs from **the merge base**, something like `git diff --name-status <the-merge-base> <branch1>; git diff --name-status <the-merge-base> <branch2>`. If you do _not_ see alpha in the output of both diffs, then add the additional information to the question and write a comment so we know that there is something else to look at.... I would be very surprised if the assumption is not the problem.

Comment: Or simpler, to find commits that modified `alpha/` on _both_ branches: `gitk master...branch -- alpha/` (or `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` with the same arguments)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing could happen if someone else did a force push on `main`.

Check the history of your branch since its fork point from main :

```
git log --graph --oneline --name-status origin/master..HEAD
```

If you see commits which modify `alpha/` then a part of the history on `main` was rewritten.

---

To fix that, you can start from your branch, run `git rebase -i origin/main` and get rid of the inappropriate commits.

Or you can merge, and fix the conflicts by taking the version of `alpha/` versioned in `origin/main` :

```
git restore -SW -s origin/main -- alpha/
```